# Purpose Of NullWritable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to count the number of studens who have booked a movie ticket and I wannt only one output after the reduce phase. I desire that the mapper emits the count of the number of students not the keys.
Can I use NullWritable as an Output Key so that nothing is emitted from the map side as the key to the reduce side? 
as shown below

```
context.write(NullWritable.get(),new IntWritable(1);
```

The data will be emitted to the reducer and the reducer will perform further aggregation

Please suggest if anybody has a better alternative.

Thank You in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you could emit the map output as

```
context.write(new Text("number of students"),new IntWritable(1));
```

with number of reducers set to 1 in driver.Then you could sum up the value on the reducer side.

Suppose if you only need value in the Output file and don't need key in that case you could use NullWritable.

```
context.write(NullWritable.get(),value)
```